# How to wrap each paragraph of input into separate input fields upon submit?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

So, basically, upon `<%= form_tag %>` submit, I need to make each paragraph of an `<%= text_area_tag %>` its own object, with unique ID.

I will have a Paragraph model, and they would be quite easy to create and save with separate input fields, but for the sake of convenience I need them to be created with simply one input field.

If anyone has other ideas for mass creating this kind of Paragraph model with one input, all suggestions are hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `simple_form` gem and you can override how each input is generated for the form.

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-input-components

Comment: Great, I looked into it and I think this is my best bet to do it. Thanks a lot!